# Angular 2:Invalid configuration of route 'home'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to implement routing in Angular 2 and these are my files

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import {RentedHomeComponent} from "./rented-home";
import {TenantComponent} from "./tenant.component";
import {SubTenantComponent} from "./sub-tenant.component";
import {BreadcrumbService} from "./breadcrumb.service";
import {routes, routingProviders} from "./app.routes";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {BreadcrumbComponent} from "./breadcrumb.component";
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1 class="title">This is the landing page and no Breadcrumb here</h1>
    <a routerLink="/rented-home" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">View Customer Detail</a>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    <div class="main-view">
    </div>`,
})
export class App { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule, routes ],
  declarations: [ App, HomeComponent, RentedHomeComponent, TenantComponent, SubTenantComponent, BreadcrumbComponent  ],
  providers: [routingProviders, BreadcrumbService,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {ModuleWithProviders} from "@angular/core";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import {RentedHomeComponent} from "./rented-home";
import {TenantComponent} from "./tenant.component";
import {SubTenantComponent} from "./sub-tenant.component";
import {App} from "./app";

const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home', component:App},
  {path:'rented-home', component:RentedHomeComponent, data:{title:'Rented-Home'}},
  {path:'tenant', component:TenantComponent, data:{title:'Tenant'}},
  {path:'sub-tenant', component:SubTenantComponent, data:{title:'Sub-Tenant'}}
]
export const routingProviders : any[] = [];
export const routes : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

But I'm getting - Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route 'home'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Any help on this?

Comment: I suggest in my deleted answer to change  `{path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},` to  `{path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},`. I deleted my answer because, the issue can be a problem with your App(Component)

Comment: @mickdev I tried with and without '/' but thee same error

Comment: Could there be collusion between the name `App` and an internal `App` module from Angular library? You should try to change the of your component to `AppComponent` to be sure. Beside that I can't see nothing unusual. Could you provide a plunker ?